# Odoo 13 - Invalid input syntax for type integer: "virtual_xxx" when updating One2many inside onchange

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I'm trying to update One2many field inside `onchange` method.

As documentation says I'm using `update` method, and not standard CRUD methods like `create`.

I have this piece of code:

```py
class HrExpenseSheet(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.expense.sheet"


    @api.onchange('employee_id')
    def _update_expense_ids(self):
        
        # define variables ...

        values = {
            'product_id': product_id,
            'name': name,
            'product_uom_id': product_uom_id, 
            'unit_amount': unit_amount, 
            'quantity': quantity, 
            'total_amount': total_amount
        }
            
        self.update({'expense_line_ids':[(0, 0, values)]})
```

It almost works. I get my record added to the table but after that whole table just breaks... When this code executes couple things happen:

- I'm not able to save the document because supposedly required `unit_amount` is not filled in - it clearly should be
- When I'm trying to edit that particular line I'm not able to because it takes me to a completely new record without my data filled in (but data is present on the table view)
- I'm not able to add new row because when I click the button I get error
  `psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "virtual_2509" LINE 1: ...mpany_id" = 1))  AND  (("hr_expense"."id" not in ('virtual_2...`

What the hell is happening. I've had the same code running on version 8.0 without problem but this does not work on 13.0.

Comment: is product_id and product_uom_id an integer value?

Comment: Yes it is an integer

Comment: @AnJ I have the same problem. How did you solve this?\

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar issue, but it was because I "create" the records in a M2M field using the `[(0, None, {'a': 1})` sintax. Was solved creating the lines using `model.create([{'a': 1}])`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is you're using [(0,0,{vals}] to fill values to a Many2many field.